# How to use schema component designators in xerces for java?

Tags: java, xsd, xerces, scd

I want to run SCD queries on a schema. The docs indicates that there is experimental support, but I don't see anything in the javadoc. Anyone know how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this wrapper on xerces](http://www.mathling.com/xsd/scds.html). It can locate the paths as well as generate them.