# Schema Component Designators (SCD) in Xerces?

Tags: xml, xsd, xerces, scd

From the Xerces2 Java Parser Readme page ,Changes from Previous Release section:

> This release also introduces experimental support for XML Schema
>   Component Designators (SCD)

I have been going through the Javadoc and cannot for the life of me find any methods or classes which allow for the use of schema component designators.
I have also looked at the wrapper mentioned in: 
[How to use schema component designators in xerces for java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581594/how-to-use-schema-component-designators-in-xerces-for-java)
But I would rather not use third party libraries if I can just use the Xerces API directly.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Alternatively if someone could point me in the direction of another schema parsing java library that supports SCD queries on parsed schemas then that would be much appreciated (I have tried XSOM but found its SCD methods unusable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCD is available in the xml-schema-1.1-dev branch[1] of Xerces2-j. 
Take a look at [2] if you need any implementation details.

[1] https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/java/branches/xml-schema-1.1-dev/

[2] http://ishanjayawardena.blogspot.com/2012/04/implementation-of-xml-schema-component.html